# Equivalence of Metrics.

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, equivalent-metrics

Prove the following metrics are equivalent:

$$d_1(f,g) = \sup_{N \geq{0} }  \frac{1}{2^N} \frac{\| f-g \|_N}{1 + \| f-g \|_N}$$
and $$d_2(f,g) = \sum_{N = 0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{2^N} \frac{\| f-g \|_N}{1 + \| f-g \|_N}$$
where $$\| \phi \|_N = \max _ {x \in \Omega} \{ |D^\alpha \phi(x) | : |\alpha| \leq N \}$$

with $$\alpha$$ is a multi-index

Any hint? What I tried is to see if they are in strong equivalence (because I thought it'd be easier) but I didn't get nothing interesting.
Useful information: $f$ and $g$ are smooth functions with compact support. I'm working over the space of test functions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably the easiest way to go about proving this is by showing that the identity function $I : C_c^{\infty}(X)\to C_c^{\infty}(X)$ is $(d_1, d_2)$-continuous and $(d_2, d_1)$-continuous. I recommend showing the latter first.

Comment: And what if I show if $d_1(f,g) < s$ then I can bound $d_2$? I'd be done, right?

Comment: I.e: I show $d_1(f,g) < s \to d_2(f,g) < \mbox{blah}$ then I can fix a ball with $d_2(f,g) < \epsilon$ and choose $s$ small enough to fit in it

Comment: If $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0 : d_1(f, g) < \delta \Rightarrow d_2(f, g) < \epsilon$, then you have shown $(d_1, d_2)$-continuity, yes. After that, you must show $(d_2, d_1)$-continuity.